# Run python script via python linux

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to execute a Python file via GUI. So I'm using following line to run that script. It's working fine on Windows.

```
GButton_330=tk.Button(root)
GButton_330["bg"] = "#efefef"
ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
GButton_330["font"] = ft
GButton_330["fg"] = "#000000"
GButton_330["justify"] = "center"
GButton_330["text"] = "Start"
GButton_330.place(x=340,y=170,width=70,height=25)
GButton_330["command"] = lambda: os.system('run.py')
```

But when I'm trying on Linux it says `run.py: not found`. I can't figure out the issue. `run.py` is in the same directory as `GUI.py`.

Comment: Under Linux, you cannot exeute `run.py` directly except its executable attributes are set and has proper `shebang` at the first line of the file.  Otherwise you need to use `Python` to execute the script explicitly.

Comment: Where's the "following line to run that script"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do

```
os.system('./run.py')
```

or if that doesn't work then

```
os.system('python3 run.py') # or just python for python 2
```